# Redux - React how change state with payload and another value

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

i wonder if i have some action like

```
.then((res) => {
                dispatch({
                    type: FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS,
                    payload: res
                })
            })
```

and in my reducer i want to change state with action payload. So in this case it's response from api. And some value in state eg. isLoading: false with isLoading:true

in my reducer as follows:

```
let initialState = [{
    isLoading: false,
}]

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_DATA_START:
            return [...state]
        case FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS:
            return [...state, ...action.payload]  
        case FETCH_DATA_FAILED: 
            return [state]
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

here is how assign in **case: FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS** action payload and isLoading: true.

so in final i want to make my state like this:

```
State = [{
    isLoading: true,
    items: [{}] // items is coming from response of fetch call

}]
```

how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 5):

It is more easier if your state is an `Object` instead of `Array`. Try it in your reducer:

```
let initialState = {
    isLoading: false,
    error: null,
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_DATA_START:
            return { ...state, isLoading: true }
        case FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS:
            return { ...state, items: ...action.payload, isLoading: false } 
        case FETCH_DATA_FAILED: 
            return { ...state, error: ...action.payload, isLoading: false }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: you may have forgotten `items: []` in `initialState`

Comment: You are right. But sometimes we are able to skip it on `initialState`. We can use `reselect` on selector to handle that case.

Comment: here can be some syntax error? because i'm getting : Failed to compile   Line 15:  Parsing error: Unexpected token about this three dot ...action.payload

Comment: regarding ...action.payload you may need to include a corresponding babel plugin
this one https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread

Comment: @George.S tha't right. BTW, ECMAScript 6 supports spread properties for object literals.